# how to notify automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a webapp, which asks for email-id and name. I have made it to search for seat availability for an institution. Backend works: using node.js I have used API to fetch information whether the seat is available or not. As soon as it gets a vacancy it is about to notify that person via his/her email id I received. I am stuck on how to mail/notify him(there could be many) as soon as I see that vacant seat?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to send the email, I'd recommend using a transactional email API such as SendGrid.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-nodejs/

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com', // Change to your recipient
  from: 'test@example.com', // Change to your verified sender
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
}

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response[0].statusCode)
    console.log(response[0].headers)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

You can modify the `to` property inside `msg` to be an array of strings, allowing you to send to multiple recipients:

```
const msg = {
  to: ['test@example.com', 'test2@example.com'], // Change to your recipients
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to send the email using NodeJS - then you can use NodeMailer Package

it will allow you to send emails on behalf of yourself automatically

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer

Example :

```
     var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport( {
              service: 'gmail',
              auth: {
                user: "email@gmail.com",
                pass: "password"
              }
            });
            var mailOptions = {
              to: "targetEmail@gmail.com",
// This must be the same as the auth 
              from: "email@gmail.com",

              subject: 'EMAIL TITLE IN INBOX ',
     text:"Email Text "
            };
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
               console.log("Success Email Sent!");
            });
```

Be aware that if you use Gmail as example, you need to enable this option in your Gmail settings

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Also be aware of how many messages you are expecting to send, if the number of messages is more than 500 per day , then google wiil rate limit your account and you might need to contact them to unlock it

if you are expecting more than that number then, then you might consider subscribing to SMTP server like SendGrid or Constant Contact.

Comment: Do not use this in a production application. You will end up in the spam inbox a lot at any reasonable scale. Use a transactional email API instead and pay a very small amount of money to ensure good delivery rates.

Comment: @Jordan Yep, I was editing this part already about the rate limiting expected , if still in prototyping stage, then this might be suitable for now.